# concurrency in go -Taking same time with different no of CPU

Tags: go

I am running a go concurrent program with the below two case and observed that It is taking same time irrespective of no of **CPU** it using while execution.

**Case1**: When cpuUsed = 1

```
program took 3m20.973185s.
```

when I am increasing the no of CPU used.

**Case2**: when cpuUsed = 8

```
program took 3m20.9330516s.
```

Please find the below Go code for more details.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math/rand"
    "runtime"
    "sync"
    "time"
)

var waitG sync.WaitGroup
var cpuUsed = 1
var maxRandomNums = 1000


func init() {
    maxCPU := runtime.NumCPU() //It'll give us the max CPU :)

    cpuUsed = 8 //getting same time taken for 1 and 8
    runtime.GOMAXPROCS(cpuUsed)

    fmt.Printf("Number of CPUs (Total=%d - Used=%d) \n", maxCPU, cpuUsed)
}

func main() {

    start := time.Now()
    ids := []string{"rotine1", "routine2", "routine3", "routine4"}

    waitG.Add(4)
    for i := range ids {
        go numbers(ids[i])
    }
    waitG.Wait()

    elapsed := time.Since(start)
    fmt.Printf("\nprogram took %s. \n", elapsed)
}

func numbers(id string) {
    rand.Seed(time.Now().UnixNano())
    for i := 1; i <= maxRandomNums; i++ {
        time.Sleep(200 * time.Millisecond)
        fmt.Printf("%s-%d  ", id, rand.Intn(20)+20) 

    }
    waitG.Done()
}
```

Comment: You probably should read about goroutines and threads https://golangbot.com/goroutines/

Comment: Your goroutines spend pretty much all of their time sleeping. Increasing the number of processes only helps with things that are limited by CPU power. time.Sleep is the exact opposite.

Comment: Your `numbers()` function sleeps 99.999% of the time, and does work for 0.001% of the time. Launching multiple goroutines you'll be able to cut the 0.001%, but the sleep time will remain the same. Also `rand.Intn()` allows concurrent access because it serializes access, so even without the sleep you unlikely to see performance gain. Create and use a separate `rand.Rand` for each goroutine, and get rid of the sleep to see performance gain.

Comment: what do you mean by `cpu increase` ? And how does more cpu can handle more faster the same number of routines ? Note also that you are not testing against a fixed size workload. Every time you add a routine, it adds up its own workload. So the workload is never spread out to maximize the throughput across available physical cpus, it is jut pilled up and siloed into logical routines. There is no point in modifying the runtime settings if you dont understand what you do. You can play with something like this before going further https://go.dev/play/p/WZe2pP1U7X7

Comment: Ten people can write and send a letter just as quickly when there's one postbox or ten postboxes, most of the task doesn't require the postbox. You picked a task which doesn't use the CPU, sleeping.

Answer (score 1):

you will find out:

**total time (3 min 20s) = 200s = sleep(200ms) * loops(1000)**

Let's simplify your code and focus on CPU usage:

1. Remove the Sleep, which does not use the CPU at all
2. fmt.Println as a stdio, does not use the CPU
3. Random number did nothing but introduce uncertainty into the program, remove it
4. The only code that takes CPU in the goroutine is the "rand.Intn(20)+20", making it a constant addition
5. Increase the "maxRandomNums"

then your code will be like this, run it again

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "runtime"
    "sync"
    "time"
)

var waitG sync.WaitGroup
var cpuUsed = 1
var maxRandomNums = 1000000000

func init() {
    maxCPU := runtime.NumCPU() //It'll give us the max CPU :)

    cpuUsed = 8 //getting same time taken for 1 and 8
    runtime.GOMAXPROCS(cpuUsed)

    fmt.Printf("Number of CPUs (Total=%d - Used=%d) \n", maxCPU, cpuUsed)
}

func main() {

    start := time.Now()
    ids := []string{"rotine1", "routine2", "routine3", "routine4"}

    waitG.Add(4)
    for i := range ids {
        go numbers(ids[i])
    }
    waitG.Wait()

    elapsed := time.Since(start)
    fmt.Printf("\nprogram took %s. \n", elapsed)
}

func numbers(id string) {
    // rand.Seed(time.Now().UnixNano())
    for i := 1; i <= maxRandomNums; i++ {
        // time.Sleep(200 * time.Millisecond)
        // fmt.Printf("%s-%d  ", id, rand.Intn(20)+20)
        _ = i + 20

    }
    waitG.Done()
}
```